# react native TouchableHighlight how change overlay color in arrow function

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

When I am using touchableHighlight, I am able to change the overlay color like this:

```
 <TouchableHighlight
                     onPress={this.toggle.bind(this)}
                     underlayColor="#f1f1f1">
```

However, when I use the arrow function like this:

```
    <TouchableHighlight
                     underlayColor="#f1f1f1"
                     onPress = {() => {
                     this.toggle(!this.state.modalVisible)}}>
```

UnderlayColor won't change. Any idea how I could use the arrow function and change the underlayColor?

Comment: There is no such issue... with arrow function i have tried both the case.... check may be there is some other reason

Answer (score 0):

1.
If in constructor or class, you can use

```
this.state = {
underlayColor:"#f1f1f1"
}
```

In any other function

```
this.setState({underlayColor:"#f1f1f1"})
```

2.

```
<TouchableHighlight
 onPress={this.toggle.bind(this)}
 underlayColor={this.state.underlayColor}>

toggle =()=>{
 this.setState({
 underlayColor:"new color"
})
}
```